# How to change logout method to GET in laravel 6?

Tags: laravel, controller, routes

I'm using laravel 6 and I  want to change the method of logout auth. How I can do that?

I run :

```
php artisan route:list
```

and I get default laravel logout method is POST :

```
Route::post('/logout', 'LoginController@logout');
```

and I want change to GET :

```
Route::get('/logout', 'LoginController@logout');
```

How I can change the route method ? And where I can custom the logout controller ?

Answer (score 3):

In your `routes.php`, add `Route::get('/logout', 'LoginController@logout');` to the top of `Auth::routes()` so it overrides the default logout route.

In your LoginController@logout() method: simply do `auth()->logout()` and redirect as appropriate

Comment: Why would you want to set the logout route to a get instead of a post

Comment: Sometimes, you just need the logout triggered on button click, without the extra logic of converting it to a POST request and adding csrf. Having /logout being a POST method doesn't really make sense as you're not sending anything to the server. It's more suited as a GET request